# How to get react native pixel color when clicked?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using a react native app and I want to get the pixel color of the image that I am clicking. I want to do something based the color of the selected pixel. Is it possible to that in react native. I already tried working with `react-native-get-pixel-color` and it doesn't work.
Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

The error by `react-native-get-pixel-color`

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file 'F:\Testing\React Native\TestingImageAreaSelect\node_modules\react-native-get-pixel-color\android\build.gradle' line: 23

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-get-pixel-color'.
> Plugin with id 'maven' not found.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-get-pixel-color'.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 4s
5 actionable tasks: 5 up-to-date
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: Did you used GetPixelColor.pickColorAt(x, y) method?

Comment: No, can you elaborate, please? If you meant about the package, then I couldn't even run my app with that package, it keeps giving me error.

Comment: What error did it gave?

Comment: https://github.com/dudyn5ky1/react-native-get-pixel-color/issues/8 Have you tried the following solution?

Comment: sorry, can confirm it's still not working. I think the library is pretty old, there are some issues with version and I can see a lot of warning in my console too.